# ant-cannot find symbol@Test

Tags: selenium, ant, junit

I am trying to compile following class that has just the one function in it.

public class TestAnnotations {

```
@Test
public void testLogin(){
    System.out.println("Testing Login");
}
```

When I run the file as JUNIt it works but when I try to run the file from build.xml it gives me the following error: cannot find symbol @Test. I do have the Junit.jar file at the right location. Here is my build.xml script:

```
    <property environment = "env"/>

    <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}" />

    <property name="ws.jars" value="D:/Data/eclipse/workspace/SeleniumDemo/lib/oracle_junit/junit.jar"/>
    <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build" />
    <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src" />
    <property name="test.reportDir" value="C:/reports"/>

    <path id="testcase.path">
        <pathelement location="${test.dest}" />
        <fileset dir="${ws.jars}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
            <mkdir dir="build/classes" />           
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${test.dest}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends = "init, clean">
        <delete includeemptydirs= "true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir = "${test.dest}" includes = "**/*"/>
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir = "${test.dest}"/>
        <javac 
            debug = "true"              
            destdir = "${test.dest}"
            includeantruntime = "false"
            srcdir = "${test.src}"
            target = "1.7"
            classpath = "${test.classpath}"
        >
        </javac>

    </target>


    <target name="run">     
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}">

            <include name="tests/TestAnnotations.class" />

        </fileset>

    </target>
```

ant builds the project successfully but it fails at compilation

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add the jUnit library to the classpath so Ant knows where it is?

```
...
<classpath path="path/to/your/junit.jar"/>
...
```

Comment: @Shabeer you may have a look at this template, too: https://github.com/mplacona/java-junit-template-project

Comment: Thank you putting junit.jar path in classpath worked. Thank you.

Comment: I got into another issue. I am trying to use IEDriver in my script but when I compile in ant I get error:  error: package org.openqa.selenium.ie does not exist. How can I resolve this issue please