# Issue with ANT compile

Tags: testing, ant, testng

Trying to compile build.xml file and receive following error

***1. java:3: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
2. java:7: error: cannot find symbol @Test***

I've attached my build.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project []>
<project name="Selenium" default="usage" basedir=".">
  <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
  <property environment="env" />
  <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}" />
  <property name="ws.jars" value="/Users/stakhivigor/Documents/Automation/jars" />
  <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build" />
  <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src" />
  <property name="ng.result" value="test-output" />
  <target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
      <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="test.classpath"
      refid="classpath_jars" />
  </target>
  <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
    <tstamp>
      <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
    </tstamp>
    <condition property="ANT" value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"
      else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
      <os family="windows" />
    </condition>
    <taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
      classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
  </target>
  <!-- all -->
  <target name="all">
  </target>
  <!-- clean -->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${test.dest}" />
  </target>
  <!-- compile -->
  <property name="src" location="src" />
  <property name="build" location="build" />
  <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false" />
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
      <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*" />
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..." />
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}" />
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}" />
    <echo message="compiling..." />
    <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" destdir="${test.dest}"
      srcdir="${test.src}" target="1.5" classpath="${test.classpath}">
    </javac>
  </target>
  <!-- build -->
  <target name="build" depends="init">
  </target>
  <!-- run -->
  <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="Automation Test">
      <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>
  </target>
  <target name="usage">
    <echo> ant run will execute the test 
    </echo>
  </target>
  <path id="test.c">
    <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar" />
  </path>
  <target name="makexsltreports">
    <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output" />
    <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"
      out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c"
      processor="SaxonLiaison">
      <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/" />
      <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
    </xslt>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: It looks like the testng jar is not in the classpath.

Comment: that weird, because I put testing file to jar folder

Comment: Hav a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19484832/6271180), it looks like your problem. Try just adding :
`<classpath path="path/to/your/testng.jar"/>`